# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"TestSubject"). Expected elements are <{}Test>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

There are  several help topics concerning the issue 
but I haven't found a solution that solved my issue.
I appreciate guidance in solving the issue.

I tried generating xml thru Marshal and below xml is what is generated from code.

I have to work with xml structure below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Test>
    <testSubject>
        <firstName>test1</firstName>`enter code here`
        <lastNAme>lastname</lastNAme>
        <ssn>123456</ssn>
    </testSubject>
</Test>
```

code

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Test")
public class Test { 
      public Test()
      {
          testSubject = new ArrayList<TestSubject>();
      }

    List<TestSubject> testSubject;

    @XmlElement(name = "testSubject", type = TestSubject.class)         
    public List<TestSubject> getTestSubject() {
        return testSubject;
    }

    public void setTestSubject(List<TestSubject> testSubject) {
        this.testSubject = testSubject;
    }
```

TestSubject class

```
public class TestSubject {

    String firstName;
    String lastNAme;
    int ssn;

//getters and setters

}
```

**//unmarshall code in my main class**

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
File xml = new File("c://testSubjects.xml");
Test tests = (Test) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
```

***Exception***

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"TestSubject"). Expected elements are <{}Test>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
```

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure your XML is as you've shown it?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you aren't showing us the real XML you are trying to unmarshal. The error you are seeing would happen if your XML was in the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<testSubject>
    <firstName>test1</firstName>
    <lastNAme>lastname</lastNAme>
    <ssn>123456</ssn>
</testSubject>
```

instead of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Test>
    <testSubject>
        <firstName>test1</firstName>
        <lastNAme>lastname</lastNAme>
        <ssn>123456</ssn>
    </testSubject>
</Test>
```

Simply correct it.

As the stacktrace says

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"TestSubject"). Expected elements are <{}Test>
```

Your are getting a `<testSubject>` node where you are expecting a `<Test>` node. Since `<Test>` is meant to be the root node, that's where it occurs.

Comment: I'm using the correct xml as specified (With root node as "Test").Still the same exception.Not able to idnetify the cause

Comment: @user I'll have to ask that you reverify everything because it works for me.

Comment: I have another JAXB question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751255/importing-xml-document-into-entity-structure-created-by-jaxb?noredirect=1#comment40267964_25751255