# importing xml document into entity structure created by jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to use jaxb to import an xml document into an entity structure that was created by jaxb. I downloaded [jaxb 2.2.7](https://jaxb.java.net/) and am using the create-marshal sample included in that download, but I changed the content of `po.xsd` to the following:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="businessDocument" type="BusinessDocument"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="CompoundId">
    <xsd:attribute name="root"  type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="extension" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="EntityType1">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="typeId" type="CompoundId"/>
        <xsd:element name="entityTitle" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="BusinessDocument">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="typeId" type="CompoundId"/>
        <xsd:element ref="documentTitle" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="entity1" type="EntityType1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I then created `po.xml` with the following structure, which is intended to match `po.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<businessDocument>
    <typeId root="docroot1" extension="docext1"/>
    <documentTitle>first document</documentTitle>
    <entity1>
        <typeId root="innerroot1" extension="innerext1"/>
        <entityTitle>inner title</entityTitle>
    </entity1>
</businessDocument>
```

I changed `Main.java` to the following form in order to import `po.xml` into the entity structure that was created from `po.xsd` using the `create-marshal` sample `build.xml` file:

```
package mainpackage;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import primer.po.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String filename = "C:\\Temp\\jaxb\\apps\\create-marshal\\po.xml";
        InputStream is = getInputStream(filename);
        try { unmarshal(BusinessDocument.class, is);} 
        catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static InputStream getInputStream(String filename){
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(filename);
            is.close(); 
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return is;
    }

    public static <T> T unmarshal( Class<T> docClass, InputStream inputStream )throws JAXBException {
        String packageName = docClass.getPackage().getName();
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( packageName );
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<T> doc = (JAXBElement<T>)u.unmarshal( inputStream );
        return doc.getValue();
    }
}
```

The compile portion of build.xml is:

```
<!--compile Java source files-->
  <target name="compile" description="Compile all Java source files">
    <echo message="Compiling the schema..." />
    <mkdir dir="gen-src" />
    <mkdir dir="gen-src/primer/po" />
    <xjc schema="po.xsd" package="primer.po" destdir="gen-src">
      <produces dir="gen-src/primer/po" includes="**/*.java" />
    </xjc>
    <echo message="Compiling the java source files..." />
    <mkdir dir="classes" />
    <javac destdir="classes" debug="on">
      <src path="src" />
      <src path="gen-src" />
      <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
  </target>
```

But I am getting the following stack trace:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.IOException: Read error]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at mainpackage.Main.unmarshal(Main.java:39)
    at mainpackage.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read error
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Native Method)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEntityManager.java:2932)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:704)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with `documentTitle` in you `xsd`. You have the `ref` but couldnt find the definition anywhere.

Comment: I used your xsd (added that documentTitle) and xml. Genereated the classes using eclipse, its working fine. Hopefully clear your class files and regenerate should fix the problem.

Comment: Great, glad you fixed the weird problem. You can upvote if you really find them helpful!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
is = new FileInputStream(filename);
is.close();
```

So, you try to unmarshal XML from file using `FileInputStream` for that, but you **close** `is` before `unmarshal` not after ?

**UPDATE**

I have never used XSD for JAXB, just its annotations on domain classes, but your XSD is stil wrong. Try remove `documentTitle` element from the beginning of your XSD.

Comment: Added some comment regarding your XSD.

Comment: In addition to your suggestions, I also had to change the order of the first two `xsd:element` declarations at the top of `po.xsd` so that `<xsd:element name="businessDocument" type="BusinessDocument"/>` goes ahead of `<xsd:element name="documentTitle" type="xsd:string"/>`

Comment: Removing `<xsd:element name="documentTitle" type="xsd:string"/>` just threw another error, but I resolved by re-ordering the two `xsd:element` declarations, as per my comment.