# Iterate XML input stream with System.out.println()

Tags: java, xml

I am importing an xml file into an InputStream and then trying to unmarshalling it using jaxb.  I want to read out what is in the input stream so that I can better diagnose subsequent steps.  How do I iterate through the xml content in an inputstream?

Here is the method that needs to iterate the InputStream:

```
public static <T> T unmarshal( Class<T> docClass, InputStream inputStream )throws JAXBException {
    String packageName = docClass.getPackage().getName();
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( packageName );
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    int r;
    try {
        while ((r = inputStream.read()) > 0) {
        //how do i iterate the inputstream?
        //System.out.println() for each line in the xml file
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    Object object = u.unmarshal( inputStream );//this throws error.  I want to see what is inside
    System.out.println(object.getClass());
    System.out.println(JAXBIntrospector.getValue(object).getClass());
    JAXBElement<T> doc = (JAXBElement<T>)object;//u.unmarshal( inputStream );
    return doc.getValue();
}
```

Just for kicks, the code that calls the above method is:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String filename = "C:\\Temp\\jaxb\\apps\\create-marshal\\po.xml";
    InputStream is = getInputStream(filename);
    try { unmarshal(BusinessDocument.class, is);} 
    catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static InputStream getInputStream(String filename){
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(filename);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return is;
}
```

---

### **EDIT:**

The output in the console from running @Rp- 's code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<businessDocument>
    <typeId root="docroot1" extension="docext1"/>
    <documentTitle>first document</documentTitle>
    <entity1>
        <typeId root="innerroot1" extension="innerext1"/>
        <entityTitle>inner title</entityTitle>
    </entity1>
</businessDocument>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at mainpackage.Main.unmarshal(Main.java:44)
    at mainpackage.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1414)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1059)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:200)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use `BufferedReader` to read the streams. Something like

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: +1 and credit for the answer.  Just out of curiosity, do you know what is causing the resulting error?  I posted it as an edit to my original post above.

Comment: I think, your `inputStream` is already read. Try removing any operations on `inputStream` and try, Like remove the whole while block where you try to read the inputStream.

Comment: Thank you.  That detail is not really important because I can just comment out the whole iterator to look at the rest of my code.  This is part of another problem.  Are you willing to look at that also?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751255/importing-xml-document-into-entity-structure-created-by-jaxb